# Is there a way to make my function run faster?

Tags: python, performance

I have this function, which task is to find out how many numbers, can be selected from the list in such a way, that the difference between any two selected numbers is not greater than t. How can I make it so that its time complexity is O(nlogn)?

```
def find_numbers(num_list, t):
    sorted_list=sorted(num_list)
    counter=0
    k=0
    n=0
    for i in range(len(sorted_list)):
        for j in range(k, len(sorted_list)):
            if sorted_list[j]-sorted_list[k]<=t:
                counter+=1
            else:
                break
        k+=1
    
        if counter>n:
            n=counter
        counter=0
    return n
```

Some examples of how it should work

```
print(find_numbers([2, 7, 14, 11, 7, 15], 11)) # 5
print(find_numbers([4, 2, 7, 1], 0)) # 1
print(find_numbers([7, 3, 1, 5, 2], 2)) # 3
```

In the third example, three numbers can be selected from the list [7,3,1,5,2]: 3, 1 and 2, and the differences between these numbers are all at most 2.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your general design, of sorting the list, then scanning through to see what the longest run of numbers separated by no more than `t` it is sound.

However, you can be more efficient with your scan if you realize you don't need to reset `j` each time you increase `i`. All numbers up to `sorted_list[j]` that were within `t` of `sorted_list[i]` will also be within that range of `sorted_list[i+1]`, since the latter is larger. This means the scan can be `O(n)` rather than `O(n**2)`:

```
def find_numbers(num_list, t):
    sorted_list=sorted(num_list)
    n = 0
    j = 1  # j points to the first index that might be larger by more than t
    for i in range(len(sorted_list)):
        while j < len(sorted_list) and sorted_list[j] - sorted_list[i] < t:
            j += 1
        if j - i > n:  # no need to manually count, the indexes can do that for us
            n = j - i
    return n
```

There might be a slightly more elegant way to code this, but this version solves the complexity issue you were asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `zip`

```
def find_numbers(num_list, t):
    return return len([i for i in zip(num_list, num_list[1:]) if i[0]-i[1] <= t])
```

Executions:

```
In [1]: print(find_numbers([2, 7, 14, 11, 7, 15], 11))
5

In [2]: print(find_numbers([4, 2, 7, 1], 0))
1

In [3]: print(find_numbers([7, 3, 1, 5, 2], 2))
2
```